# Checking ClassManifest for subtypes in Scala

Tags: scala, manifest, implicit, subtype

I want to compare two class-manifests (gotten through implicits) to check if class A is extending trait B. The below code should yield true in the case where I ask if the class extends the interface:

```
trait X[T,S]

class Y extends X[Double,Int]


val mX = implicitly[ClassManifest[X[Double,Int]]]
val mY = implicitly[ClassManifest[Y]]

println(mX <:< mY)

println(mY <:< mX)

println(mX,mY)
```

However, I get the following output from the terminal:

```
felix@felix-UX32VD:~/Desktop$ scala Test.scala
false
false
(Main$$anon$1@7ad0e999.type#Main$$anon$1$X[Double, Int],Main$$anon$1@7ad0e999.type#Main$$anon$1$Y)
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of Manifests is broken. This is the reason why they are replaced with [TypeTags](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags) in 2.10, which are working directly on the underlying types:

```
scala> typeTag[Y].tpe <:< typeTag[X[Double,Int]].tpe
res21: Boolean = true

scala> typeOf[Y] <:< typeOf[X[Double,Int]]
res22: Boolean = true
```

In 2.10 the idea was to deprecate the use of Manifests, but because the quality of the new reflection library is still not yet on the right level, this idea was declined. This means that Manifests still can be used but one still keep in back of one's mind that that they will be erased from the stdlib one day.

Comment: Imagine my tears as I just finished adding class-manifests to my trait and a bunch of implementing classes :'( Oh lord... well, at least now I can pass time tomorrow :/

Comment: In 2.10.0 manifests are not deprecated, because reflection ended up experimental. We do plan to deprecate manifests though, when reflection becomes polished enough.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: Yes, I missed that. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Search+replace went a long way for me :) I already implemented my program with TypeTags now and it works even with generics :)
Can you guys maybe tell me if multiple context-bounds is something new? I saw some other post using a generic function in a way like this:   func[T: Numeric : TypeTag ] which is kinda cool! Also, will I always need to import TypeTag and typeOf functions?

Comment: Multiple context bounds are not new in 2.10 and yes you always must import the types you need. Maybe in future, when reflection and macros are not experimental any more, some types will be added to Predef to make their handling easier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are not actually interested in the subtype relation between the `ClassManifest`s, but rather in the subtype relation between the erased types. Maybe this works for you:

```
println(mX <:< mY) // false
println(mX.erasure.isAssignableFrom(mY.erasure)) // true

println(mY <:< mX) // false
println(mY.erasure.isAssignableFrom(mX.erasure)) // false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to go with sschaefs answer since it is much more "propelling" for me :)